# Cardano-node nix-build error: attribute 'ff' in selection path 'scripts.ff.node' not found

Tags: nix, cardano

Using the recommended nix build method from [this guide](https://testnets.cardano.org/en/cardano/get-started/installing-and-running-the-cardano-node/building-the-node-using-nix/) for a cardano-node from scratch (on Debian or Ubuntu latest) running this command:

```
$ nix-build -A scripts.ff.node -o ff-node-local
```

I get the following error:

```
error: attribute 'ff' in selection path 'scripts.ff.node' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

To get past that error, try using a more updated [guide here](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.html), and run the following nix-build command instead:

```
nix-build -A scripts.mainnet.node -o mainnet-node-local
```